# Need a logic to generate serial number for the items having parent and child mappings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Need a logic to generate serial number for the items having parent and child mappings.

Below is the sample item mapping( the real system has more than 20 levels) with four levels.
[image]
The generated mapping should be

```
100- 1
102- 2
104- 3
106 -4
105 -5
109 -6
103- 7
107- 8
```

The sample data generation scripts

```
create table #test(Childid int, parentid int, Sno int)

insert into #test (Childid,parentid)
values (100,0),(102,100),(103,100),(104,102),(105,102),(106,104),(107,103),(109,105)

select * from #test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you don't want to use cursors, you could try [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
with cte as (
    select
        t.childid, t.parentid,
        cast(t.childid as nvarchar(max)) as pth
    from test as t
    where t.parentid = 0

    union all

    select
        t.childid, c.parentid,
        c.pth + '.' + cast(t.childid as nvarchar(max)) as pth
    from test as t
        inner join cte as c on c.childid = t.parentid
)
select
    t.childid,
    t.parentid,
    row_number() over(order by pth) as sno 
from cte as c
    inner join test as t on t.childid = c.childid
order by pth
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4dd6a/16)

Comment: Hi Roman,

What if the the item number 105 comes before 104? The sort based on the path always list 104 before 105

Comment: do you have any other columns, like sort order, which specify that 105 comes before 104?

Comment: suppose you have an id in your table and 105 is before 104. here's example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a84e4/3

Comment: Nope. Actually what I meant is under 102 we have 104 and 105( also sno are generated as per your code--that was cool) and am trying to move an item 111 between 104 and 105 ( believe me , the application allows), in that case i cant go with this approach. If i insert row by row in between i can simply increment other rows. But am trying to do it in set based approach , the new items can be inserted at any level together. Also i will try Sqlfiddle too.

Comment: So please clarify you situation. You have several rows inserted and sno calculated, then you want to insert some other rows and recalculate sno? How you schema defines that 111 goes between 104 and 105? or you want to pass 111 and tell that you want to insert row "after row 104"?

Comment: I mistook, the inserts will happen only in the end of the sub level, so no issues.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server >= 2008 there is a type, [hierarchyid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)  that should be used exactly for this.

> The hierarchyid data type is a variable length, system data type. Use hierarchyid to represent position in a hierarchy.